# How to find what file in winsxs is generating a crash?

Tags: windows, crash, debug

I have a program that is generating a msvcr80.dll error and crashing. I would like to find out what is happening, so I could find if the program is using the wrong version of that file. Is there a sysinternals that would accomplished that or is there any other option? Windows 7 64. thanks

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: ManagementConsole.exe
  Application Version:  11.0.0.2343
  Application Timestamp:    4ec39f8c
  Fault Module Name:    MSVCR80.dll
  Fault Module Version: 8.0.50727.4940
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ca2b271
  Exception Code:   40000015
  Exception Offset: 000046b4
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1046
  Additional Information 1: 424b
  Additional Information 2: 424b0a39cf53034f77d974491bd5eb69
  Additional Information 3: 36ce
  Additional Information 4: 36ce8243db317e50f33a860a6d6f8a6d
```

Comment: How about more specific information about the error and the crash?  It would be unusual for a program to look for msvcr80.dll  in the winsxs directory.  Something doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, update OP

Comment: You wanted to know which application it was? The name of the application is **ManagementConsole.exe**  Verify you have the latest version of the MS Visual C Runtime that contained MSVCR80.dll within it.  It would be extremely old though.

Comment: Looks like this is a [common issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=ManagementConsole.exe+40000015+site:forum.acronis.com).

Comment: Also, its [likely this is programming error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5115611/94928) on the part of the vendor and not something you can correct yourself.

Comment: Yeah but messing with some dll's the program usually works, like if you install one version then remove, then install other, etc.. very badly coded certainly. But I would like to trace what exactly is causing the program to crash. Can someone tell me how?

Comment: @heavyd Are you there pal?

Comment: @FernandoSBS, I'm not sure what your mean by messing with some DLLs.  If the application has a bug, then you may have to wait for the vendor to fix it.

Comment: the bug is about incorrect version of dll from the system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19512/discussion-between-heavyd-and-fernandosbs).